# Laravel testing database migration fails due to Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-migrations

I installed Laravel Passport and migrated the new tables just fine in my database. But when I try to run migrations for the testing database, ie. `artisan migrate --database=testing` I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'oauth_auth_codes' already exists
```

The only table that exists in the testing database is the `migrations` table. It looks as if it's checking the regular database and seeing this Passport table instead of checking the testing database. Did I miss something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan ...` commands will use your `.env` variables for configuration, so yes, unless you specified which database connection to use, it will use your default `.env`'s `DB_` variables.

You can define something like a `.env.testing`, then re-run as `php artisan migrate --env=testing` to use that file instead of your default one.

`.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=database
...
# Host, Port, Username, Password,
```

`.env.testing`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=testing
...
# Host, Port, Username, Password,
```